# Getting the values from a JSON into a discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js bot where all the command data is stored in a JSON file and when the `help` command is run, I want it to iterate through the JSON, at the level the user entered.

So far, I've managed to check if the value entered is a command or a category, and I have been able to `console.log` all the information and it shows the correct data I want to display on the embed.

For example, in my JSON file I have:

```json
{
  "category1": {
    "command1": {
      "Aliases": [],
      "Description": "Runs a command"
    }
  }
}
```

When I do the `console.log()` when the user runs `g!help category1` it outputs:

```
command1
Runs a command
```

and when it sends the embed I get:

```
[object Object]
undefined
```

Here is the part of the code which iterates through the JSON and adds the data to the embed:

```js
for (ctg in help_data) {
  if (args[0] === ctg) {
    embed.setTitle(ctg)
    for (command in help_data[ctg]) {
      var cmd = command
      var desc = help_data[ctg][command].Description

      console.log(cmd)
      console.log(desc)

      embed.addField({
        "name": cmd,
        "Value": desc
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it changes between the `console.log` and the `embed.addField`, if someone could please explain why this happens and how I can fix it, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`embed.addField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) takes three parameters, the first is the `name` of the field, the second is its `value`. Both of these are strings. In your example, your first argument is an object that gets converted to a string (and hence becomes `[object Object]`) and the second one (as you don't provide anything) is `undefined`.

To fix this, you can either add the two strings like this:

```js
embed.addField(cmd, desc);
```

Or use the [`addFields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) method instead, that accepts an object like this:

```js
embed.addFields({
  name: cmd,
  value: desc,
});
```